# Separate differential backup from one restored baseline

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup

I work on a team that customises software, part of this customisation is stored as records in a database, part is customisations to the schema itself and there are often some specific records in the database too.

I'd like to create a baseline version of the database and back it up normally. Then for each customer I restore the baseline database under the customer's name and customise it as usual. I'd then like to do a differential backup of the database from the baseline point to the current point and shelve the differential backup for that customer, I expect about 0.1-0.2% changed data. When I need to do more work for that customer I restore the baseline backup and their differential backup, do the work then backup again, replacing the shelved baseline backup.

This is similar to [Differential databases (not backups)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/62240/4329) but using backups.

Can I have different differential backups that can be restored against a single baseline?

Can I do a new differential backup from the same starting point or would I need to do incremental backups.

Any problems or experiences with this sort of approach?

Answer (score 4):

The question is a little ambiguous, but either of the two ways I see to interpret it would work:

Starting point: A [differential backup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175526.aspx) captures all changes from the last full backup (the 'differential base').

Both scenarios below start by creating the baseline database and taking a full (not copy only) backup of it.

#### Scenario 1 - Continuing differentials

- Restore the baseline
- Restore the latest differential for customer X (if any)
- Make changes for customer X
- Perform a new *differential* backup for customer X

You need to keep the full baseline and the latest differential for each customer in this scenario.

#### Scenario 2 - Separate full backups

- Restore the latest full backup for customer X (or the baseline if a new customer)
- Make changes for customer X
- Perform a new *full* backup for customer X

You need to keep the baseline (for new customers) and the latest full backup for each customer in this scenario.

---

In **scenario 1**, the size of the differentials will grow larger over time, but never larger than the size of the current database for each customer.

Restoring for each customer requires two steps: baseline, then customer-specific single latest differential. Previous differentials can be discarded if necessary.

**Scenario 2** will require more storage space than scenario 1, as each customer gets a full copy of their current database.

Restoring for each customer is a simple one-step process. Previous per-customer full backups may be discarded.

---

As [usr](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/6819/usr) mentioned in a comment, one drawback to either set up is it makes it more difficult to apply a change to all customers.

As always, a known good current database validated by `DBCC CHECKDB` with the appropriate options is needed, and the only valid backup is one you have tested to restore successfully (and pass the checkdb tests). It may be a good idea to keep the historical backups, at least for a time, in a case a customer ever wants to revert.